# android digital clock widget is gone

Tags: android, clock, android-appwidget, digital

i am developing a digital clock widget for android and here is my code but my problem here is that my widget is gone i mean there is no layout so any help?
First on Enabled:

```
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    PendingIntent anIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("upp"),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000, anIntent);
}
```

and then Receive override:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("upp")){
        ComponentName componentName =new ComponentName(context,getClass().getName());
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
        onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

and on update:

```
Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

and then inside of onUpdate first i have used the Time method to get the Hour and minute as string :

```
    onEnabled(context);
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();

int hour = today.hour;
String hh = Integer.toString(hour);

int minute = today.minute;
String mm = ":" + Integer.toString(minute);
```

and then i have showed those two strings inside of two image views with bitmap:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, getFontBitmap(context, hh, Color.WHITE, 70));

views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView2, getFontBitmap1(context, mm, Color.WHITE, 70));

ComponentName componentName =new ComponentName(context,getClass().getName());
int[] appWidgetId=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

> ```
> so any help? Thanks in advance
> ```